# mysql left join duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

ive been searching for hours but cant find a solution. its a bit complicated so i'll break it down into a very simple example

i have two tables; people and cars

people:

```
name_id    firstname
  1          john
  2          tony
  3          peter
  4          henry
```

cars:

```
name_id   car_name
   1      vw gulf
   1      ferrari
   2      mustang
   4      toyota
```

as can be seen, they are linked by name_id, and john has 2 cars, tony has 1, peter has 0 and henry has 1.

i simply want to do a single mysql search for who has a (1 or more) car. so the anwser should be john, tony, henry.

the people table is the master table, and im using `LEFT JOIN` to add the cars. my problem arises from the duplicates. the fact that the table im joining has 2 entries for 1 id in the master.

im playing around with `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` but i cant seem to get it to work.

any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: adding the query:

```
$query = "
SELECT profiles.*, invoices.paid, COUNT(*) as num 
FROM profiles 
    LEFT JOIN invoices ON (profiles.id=invoices.profileid) 
WHERE (profiles.id LIKE '%$id%') 
GROUP BY invoices.profileid
";
```

Comment: Query example is irrelevant to the question. If you have a query already for your problem, then explain what's the problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT firstname 
FROM people 
    JOIN cars ON cars.name_id = people.name_id;
```

If this doesn't work you might have to show us the full problem.

The way to propose it there's no need for a left join since you need at least a car per person. Left join is implicitely an OUTER join and is intended to return the results with 0 corresponding records in the joinned table.

Comment: here is my count query. (invoices is the cars and profiles is people)      $query = "SELECT profiles.*, invoices.paid, COUNT(*) as num FROM profiles LEFT JOIN 
invoices ON (profiles.id=invoices.profileid)
WHERE (profiles.id LIKE '%$id%') 
GROUP BY invoices.profileid ";

Answer (score 0):

try this
    `select distinct p.name_id, firstname
    from people p, cars c
    where p.name_id = c.name_id`

or use joins
    `select distinct p.name_id, firstname
    from people p
    inner join cars c
    on p.name_id = c.name_id`

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to show people that have a car, then you should use a `RIGHT JOIN`.  This will stop any results from the left table (people) to be returned if they didn't have a match in the cars table.

Group by the persons name to remove duplicates.

```
SELECT firstname
FROM people P
RIGHT JOIN cars C ON C.name_id = P.name_id
GROUP BY firstname
```